# Git Delete Intermediate Rebase Branch

Tags: git

In the middle of a rebase where I was squashing multiple commits into one, I accidently pushed it to remote. Using `git name-rev <SHA>` I found what I thought was the name of the branch the commit was on and thought a `git branch -d` would remove it.

Autocomplete wouldn't register it and the deletion failed as well. How do I delete imtermediate branches like these?

Comment: What do you mean by "intermediate branch"? What did your `push` command look like? Does running `git branch` by itself show the branch you're looking for? What about `git branch -a`?

Comment: When in the process of using rebase, Bash states REBASE|2/16. I committed and pushed accidently and it created a new branch with the unsquashed commits and named it something funky @larsks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no intermediate rebase branch.

While `git rebase` works, operationally, *as if* it created a temporary branch, there in fact no temporary branch.  Git is able to do this because branches are not actually important or relevant in Git, much of the time.

During a conflicted rebase, or at the command line prompt after an `edit` operation in an interactive rebase for instance, you will find that your session is in *detached HEAD* mode.  This means there is no current branch at all.  If you used `git push` to send a *branch name* to some other Git, what you sent is not what you are working on/with, because there is no branch name involved in what you are working on/with.<sup>1</sup>

In any case, when you run:

```
git push <remote> <refspec>
```

your Git creates or updates branch names on the given *`remote`*, not in the local repository.  So there is nothing to do with `git branch` here; `git branch` is meant for working with *local* branch names.<sup>2</sup>  If you wish to delete a branch name in the repository at the URL given by the *`remote`*, you can use `git push --delete`.

---

<sup>1</sup>It's possible that the *current commit*, by hash ID, happens to have a branch name pointing to it.  In this case the `git push` using that branch name did push the current commit.  But, in this case, the commit you're on is probably not going to be the tip commit of the branch.

<sup>2</sup>The `-r` flag to `git branch` will let you work with remote-tracking names, but there's never<sup>3</sup> any reason to bother with this.  Just have your Git send operations to the other Git, and let the other Git do them locally; your Git will update your own remote-tracking names when this succeeds.

<sup>3</sup>Insert the usual Gilbert&Suilivan routine.  If you have an ancient Git—pre-1.8.4—there are sometimes some reasons to bother, but you can also just run `git remote update --prune` there.